# What does it mean for a Docker environment variable to not have a name?

Tags: docker, environment-variables

In [the Docker repository for logstash](https://hub.docker.com/_/logstash/) I see this example for how to run it:

```
$ docker run -it --rm logstash logstash -e 'input { stdin { } } output { stdout { } }'
```

The odd thing about this is the `-e` argument.

The Docker documentation suggests that the syntax for the `-e` argument only includes strings with at least one `=` character, and that the argument is split on the first occurrence of this character to form a (key, value) pair which then defines one environment variable when the image is run.

The example above does not fit this scheme. Is the example above a valid value for `-e`? If so, what does it mean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `-e` is not an option for the docker run command, but an option for logstash. If you try to split the docker and the logstash parts you'll end up like this:

1. docker run -it --rm logstash ...
2. ... logstash -e 'input { stdin { } } output { stdout { }

So, everything including the first `logstash` is an option to the docker run command, while the second `logstash` and everything after it is a native logstash command which will be run inside the docker container.